# Expected response code 235 but got code 535 laravel send email using office365 smtp

Tags: laravel, email, office365, sendmail

I want to send email using my office365 smtp credentials in laravel application. i have make changes in my .env file for email settings as below:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@***.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

while i am trying to send email i got error like

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"info@omoyyc.com\" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 Incorrect authentication data\r\n\"
```

my email sending code is as below

```
Mail::send(array(), array(), function ($m) use ($templatecontent) {
        $m->from('customerservice@****.com', 'TEST');
        $m->to('test@gmail.com', 'Test')
                ->subject($templatecontent['subject'])
                ->setBody($templatecontent['content'], 'text/html');
    });
```

Can anyone guide me what is the issue and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache with `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: can you please tell me how to run this command on live server using cpanel. I have set following routes in my web.php to clear cache.Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return '<h1>Clear Config cleared</h1>';
});

Comment: You can run this in the same location as where you run the `composer require` or `composer update` commands (I assume local command line?) and then upload all your project files to the server so the updated files are updated on the server too

Comment: i am working on live server directly.

Comment: Do you have a terminal/command line interface/open ssh connection to the server? How have you initialized the laravel project?

Comment: I have develop whole project in local server and upload it through cpanel.

Comment: Then you should run the command locally and upload the updated project again through cpanel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183627/discussion-between-adarsh-bhatt-and-sven-hakvoort).

Answer (score 38):

I don't know if the cause is the same as OP, but I got the same error. I **fixed it by enclosing the password with double quotes.**

I'm assuming that the parsing fails when the password contains special characters.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. 
I used **Gmail SMTP**, with **less secure apps enabled** & **2-factor auth disabled**, and nothing worked. And surprisingly as @jessij mentioned, setting the password in **double-quotes worked**.

Do below in `.env` file:

```
Replace: MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
With: MAIL_PASSWORD="yourpassword"
```

Comment: i still have the same error for office365

Comment: @bhavinjr can you please check the logs and confirm if it's "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server" error?

Comment: I'm using a business email so I got to know that the sender user seems not Authorised for SMTP, Will check again once get access

Answer (score 2):

my problem is same dude, but my problem has been solved to try it :

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps
2. Take a look at Security menu -> Apps with account access menu.
3. You must turn the option "Allow less secure apps" ON.

If you already followed this step, try again your project. and if it still doesn't work, please continue this steps :

1. Visit https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha
2. Click continue button

Good Luck dude!

Comment: how this is related to office365?

Comment: @bhavinjr I am looking at the same thing and maybe you need to check web access over https://outlook.office365.com/ if you cannot access it via browser, you may not use it via laravel too. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your password contains special characters like "john@#3398", put this in " ". Then clear your php artisan cache using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Then start your `php artisan serve`.